# How to define pointer to pointer to function and how to use it in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers

My question is how to translate the following example? Is this a function, that returns int pointer?

```
int* (*function)(int, (int (*k)(int *)));
```

And can I can't write program that use it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @T.C. Awesome website.

Comment: @T.C. Have you tried cdecl.org for this? For me it outputs syntax error (even without extra parentheses)

Comment: How is the title of your question supposed to be related to its body? You mention "pointer to pointer to function" in the title, but there's nothing like that in the text and it is not even mentioned again. So, what exactly is your question about? Do you need to "define pointer to pointer to function"? Or do you need to "translate the following example"? Make up your mind and write an unambiguous question.

Comment: @MarcinJędrzejewski Needs a little massaging (it dislikes named function parameters and things named `function`, apparently).

Answer (score 1):

- It is a function-pointer
- The function returns a pointer to an int
- The function's first arg is an int
- The function's second arg is a function-pointer `k`
- k returns an int
- k takes a pointer to an int as argument

Sure you can use that in your program. It is not too unusual. There are much worse declarations i have seen.

I renamed your "function" to "F" for clarity. Then you can write:

```
int* (*F)(int, int (*kFunc)(int *) );
```

Alternative:

```
typedef int (*kFunc)(int *);
int* (*F)(int, kFunc);
```

Comment: Actually, this is ill-formed as written. There's one too many pair of parentheses.

Comment: @T.C. I guess you mean in his question? You are right. Maybe write it in a comment to the question

Answer (score 0):

You should remove extra parentheses, this is correct version:

```
    int* (*function)(int, int (*k)(int *));
```

explanation (using right-left rule):

```
int* (*fn)(int, int (*k)(int *));

fn                               : fn is a
(*fn)                            : pointer
(*fn)(int, int (*k)(int *))      : to a function taking as arguments
                                   - an int and 
                                   - function pointer 
                                     which takes a pointer to int 
                                     and returns int
int* (*fn)(int, int (*k)(int *)) : and returns a pointer to int
```

below is a short example on how to use it, also you ask for `How to define pointer to pointer to function` so below this is also included.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d05200cf5f6397b8

```
#include <iostream>

int bar(int*) {
    std::cout << "inside bar\n";
    return 0;
}

int* foo(int, int (*k)(int *)) {
    std::cout << "inside foo\n";
    k(nullptr);
    return nullptr;
}

int main() {
    int* (*function)(int, int (*k)(int *));

    function = foo;
    function(0, bar);

    // Now, as you asked for, a pointer to pointer to above function
    decltype(function) *pff;
    pff = &function;
    (*pff)(0, bar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to use pointer to a function, may be a pattern such as Factory could take advantage of the function pointer to create new objects.( Look here : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3734/Different-ways-of-implementing-factories)

May be this piece of code could help you and give ideas of how powerfull can be working with function pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <map>

// Define the func ptrs
typedef void (*TFunc)(const char *, int);
typedef int (*TFunc2)(int);

int return_value(int i)
{
    return i * 5;
}

void a( const char *name, int i )
{
    printf ("a->%s %d\n\n", name, i);
}

void b( const char *name, int i)
{
     printf ("b->%s %d\n\n", name, i);
}

struct test
{
    const char *name;
    int i;
    TFunc func;
};

static test test_array[2] = 
{
    { "a",     0,  a           },
    { "b",     1,  b           },
};

int main(int argc, char **argv, char** envp)
{
    // Check the simple case, pointer to a function
    TFunc fnc = a;
    TFunc2 fnc2 = return_value;

    fnc("blabla", 5);

    fnc = b;

    fnc("hello!", 55);

    printf ("%d\n\n",fnc2(5));

    //Check arrays of structs when there is a pointer to a fnc
    test_array[0].func(test_array[0].name, test_array[0].i);
    test_array[1].func(test_array[1].name, test_array[1].i);

    //Handle a map of functions( This could be a little implementation of a    factory )
    typedef std::map<int, TFunc > myMap;
    myMap lMap;
    lMap.insert(std::make_pair(5, a));
    lMap.insert(std::make_pair(2, b));

    if( lMap.find( 5 ) != lMap.end() )
    {
        lMap[5]("hello map 5", 1);
    }

    myMap::iterator lItFind = lMap.find(2);

    if( lItFind != lMap.end() )
    {
        lItFind->second("hello map 2", 2);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

I hope that this helps you.